# jEditable: Eliminate AJAX requests if data hasn't changed

Tags: ajax, jeditable

Anyone see potential problems with optimizing away unnecessary ajax requests like this:

```
$('.editable').editable(function(value, settings)
{
  // check if changed at all
  if(this.revert == value)
  {
    this.reset()
    return
  }

  ... fire ajax request
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks good to me.